# htaccess redirect url with multiple folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make a url redirection for my website. When I try to redirect it, nothing seems to apply. I already have a redirect is done. But I can not find how to run the second. Here's what I have in my file:

## first redirection

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mdweb-solutions\.ca$
RewriteRule !^mdweb-solutions/mdweb-solutions/ /mdweb-solutions/mdweb-solutions%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

The second relates to redirect this path:

```
mdweb-solutions/mdweb-solutions/en/
```

I want the url displays

```
http://mdweb-solutions.ca/en
```

instead of

```
http://mdweb-solutions.ca/mdweb-solutions/mdweb-solutions/en/
```

how can I do? I try stuff I found on various sites, but nothing worked.

Comment: Your rule is already doing that. What's the error you get for `http://mdweb-solutions.ca/en`?

Comment: In fact, when I put the url http://mdweb-solutions.ca/en it appears http://mdweb-solutions.ca/mdweb-solutions/mdweb-solutions/en/

I can not make it displayed only http://mdweb-solutions.ca/en

Comment: I guess `http://mdweb-solutions.ca/en/` would be working fine right?